# How to merge fields row-wise in a tab-delimited file with python

Tags: python, merge, csv

These are two example rows of my tab-delimited file:

```
id  reference_rc_001    alternative_rc_001  reference_rc_002    alternative_rc_002  reference_rc_003    alternative_rc_003
id1 0   433 0   0   69
```

I would like to merge fields every two columns. The example output should look like that. This is an step of a python script. So it has to be done with python

```
id  reference_rc_001alternative_rc_001  reference_rc_002alternative_rc_002  reference_rc_003alternative_rc_003
id1 0433    00  690
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks really horrible, is probably the worst way to do this and might be about as efficient as a donkey, but.....
I think it works.

You'll need to open the file, preferably using a `with` so you can iterate across the lines in the file. (Many other SO articles will deomstrate doing that with a decent explanation so I'm not going to.)

Then use the bit of code inside my demonstration `for` loop :

```
for line in file:
    items = line.split("\t")
    counters = range(len(items)/2)
    new_items = [items[0]] + [items[1+2*x] + items[2+2*x] for x in counters ]
    new_line = '\t'.join(new_items)
    print new_line
```

To explain :

I'm splitting each line into a list (using the tab as delimiter).
Then I'm creating a new list by indexing the n and n+1 elements of the list and adding them together (as strings).
Finally, to recreate a line of text with tab separated entries, I'm `join`ing the new list back together with tab delimiters.

Hopefully that gives you the pieces you might need for your solution.